# User profiles not deleted after import connection is deleted

Tags: 2007, user-profile

We are working on SharePoint 2007. We have around 6 profile import connections which pull data from 6 different active directory domains into the user profile store of SharePoint. Recently I deleted one of the import connection because we no longer needed the user profiles from that particular active directory domain. But after removing the connection , followed by full crawl, I can still see the user profiles from the deleted AD- import connection.And they are listed as active profiles. How can I delete the profiles from user profile store for the deleted import connection?

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2007 inactive user profiles are deleted by a timer job called My Site Cleanup Job.

During the user import process (crawl) if MOSS cannot find a user in AD/LDAP directory it marks the user deleted in the SSP user profile store without removing it. You can check these users in the SSP administration site under user profiles and properties on the View user profiles page selecting the “Profiles Missing From Import” view. You can delete the profiles here manually.

This list is the input for the “My Site Cleanup Job”.

More details - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gyorgyh/archive/2009/11/13/how-it-works-moss-2007-automatic-user-profile-removal.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply Amal.Actually they are not marked for deletion and still show up as active profile in View user profiles page . Also the my site clean up timer job shows its running successfully everyday.This active directory domain is valid and not removed from the AD or forest, just that we dont want import from this domain anymore.